# Hide a row in a datagridview (WinForms/C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, hide, datarow

Say I have a DataGridView Control, this grid is filled through a DataTable.
Now, I'd like to add some dynamic filtering, by means of a checkbox.
When the _CheckedChanged event is launched and Checked is set to true, I exectue a filter;

```
DataRow[] rows = grid.Select("foo = bar");
```

No I want to only show these records in the grid.
Now, what I thought was make a new DataTable and make it the datasource to the grid, but I see this getting cumbersome real fast when I have multiple checkboxes.
Any pointers or best practices for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the DefaultView Rowfilter property

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "foo = bar";
```

Have a look at this example

[DataTable.DefaultView Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx)